# Load Maven depencencies defined on profiles

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

I'm building a demo app with 2 different situations, first one is development and second one is production.
This is my pom.xml

```
... (version, name, etc)
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <!--DEFAULT PROFILE-->
        <env>development</env>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        ... (lombok, junit, swagger, datarest, datatest, web, webmvc...)

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <filters>
            <filter>src/main/resources/${env}.yml</filter>
        </filters>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.yml</include>
                    <include>*.xml</include>
                    <include>*.properties</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>development</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <properties>
                <start-class>com.central.CentralApplication</start-class>
                <env>development</env>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
                    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
                    <scope>runtime</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>production</id>
            <activation>
                <property>
                    <name>production</name>
                </property>
            </activation>

            <properties>
                <env>production</env>
                <start-class>com.central.CentralApplicationProd</start-class>
            </properties>

            <dependencies>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.3</version>
                    <scope>compile</scope>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.3</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.3</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2.9.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>

                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
                </dependency>

            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

</project>
```

There seems to be no problem in the pom, but when I try to create the main I need for production purposes, it can't find the Eureka and Feign dependencies (@EnableEurekaClient and @EnableFeignClients). On the other hand, if I change the `<activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>` and I put it in production profile, it loads its dependencies but, obviously, not the development ones.

How can I load both dependencies when coding?
Is my approach wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What will happen if you do `mvn -Pdesarrollo,production` compile

Comment: You shouldn't create different artifacts for different environments. You should create 1 artifact. You have a Spring Boot application, just provide the necessary information at runtime.

Comment: Antoniossss, if I run that command (I forgot to change the profile id to development, so the command I ran was mvn -Pdevelopment,production) it says that a parameter is left. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mr/Ms Deinum, I'm sorry but I don't think I understand you (I'm quite a newbie to Spring). What do you mean by artifacts?

Comment: Artefacts means the output of the maven build.  In your case the artefact is the jar file that contains the application. What @M.Deinum correctly suggests is to generate a single binary artifact ( == the same jar file ) for all the environment and change its behaviours though a configuration parameter.

Comment: @gdegain Ok, I think I do understand it now, but how can I achieve that? Like, where am I making my app generate 2 different artifacts?
Sorry if my questions are silly, as I said I am a noob in Spring, Maven...

Answer (score 0):

You should put shared dependencies outside of profiles tags in the main section of your pom file. Java classes in your code require this dependencies.

If you want to implement different logic in different environments, I recommend you to use different profiles on your [Spring configuration files](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles).

Comment: I would recommend to use most recent versions to link to ... https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.profiles

Comment: @khmarbaise thank you! I will update the link.

Comment: Thanks for your anwer too! I will take a look about that

Answer (score 0):

If you have a spring boot application you should not define any profile for any dependency.

If you need to have different configurations for dev, prod you should use spring profiles instead. That means you can define files like `application.properties` (works also with `.yml`) or `application-dev.properties` which can simply being activated via `--spring.profiels.active=dev` would mean to activate the `application-dev.properties`.

Furthermore if you need the h2 database only for testing you should simply use the `<scope>test</scope>` instead.

Which looks strange that you have defined the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` dependency in your prod profile but not for dev.

Another thing is that you have defined `<start-class>com.central.CentralApplication</start-class>` which is by default defined via the class which contains the `@SpringBootApplication` annotation on it. This means you have only a single class for that purpose and it does not matter for which environment etc.

I strongly recommend to read the spring boot documentation etc.
The question is why not defining for both.

Also I've seen that you have explicitly excluded lombok in the spring-boot-maven-plugin configuration. This means usually you have not correctly defined the dependency scope of lombok.

It is best practice **not** to define versions of dependencies yourself if you are using bom imports..otherwise you could have version mixtures which could cause issues.

One final recommendation is never use profiles to use different dependencies.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It was very helpful not only in the scope of the question but with some other problems I didn't know I had.
The h2 dependency is just in dev because it is supposed to substitute a call to another service. In that case, I should not define it with the test scope, right?
In terms of the main, I have 2 (both with the @SpringBootApplication, one for dev (without the Eureka and without Feign annotations) and one for production (with those). Is that wrong too?
I will check the lombok dependency.
Regarding bom imports, what are they? Sorry for the noob questions

Comment: If you really have two main app you should make a multi module build which contains of three modules. commons code, app1 + eureka and app2 without.. that makes it clear. H2 will substitute a call to another service? Mocking? In testing?

Comment: eureka is a service discovery thing as far as I know..so the question why not using it in dev as well?

Comment: I know it may be weird. But the idea is to have 2 services communicationg through RabbitMQ in dev (with just those 2 services) and in production, change that to Kafka and have 3 services with one of them calling to the "new" to check a parameter, instead of checking it itself like in dev (that's why the H2 db is needed).
That's the reason why Eureka (and Feign) should only be in production and not in dev and why the h2 should be in dev.
Sorry if it is weird, for my it is aswell, but those are the requirements